# Having trouble with Audio Recording in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, recording, audio-recording

I can see different recording devices in my computer as shown in following printscreen[image]
There are two options for Microphone and one is Line in. i m using Acer Aspire 4710. when i open sound recorder and start recording it either tells me that there is no recording device on this computer or if it records the audio, playing it gives no output sound. how can i solve this problem. Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As far as the sound playback issue goes, you might want to try the Windows Sound Diagnostic page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/no-sound-in-windows

With the microphones, you might want to see if you're plugging them into the right ports or try them on different computers to see if it's a hardware issue.

Comment: i have built in mike on laptop and i use it for skype chat where it works fine

Comment: That's strange that sound recording isn't working, then. Have you tried to uninstall/reinstall the driver?

Comment: i tried to update the driver but no results yet

Answer (score 1):

Right click in an empty space in the Recording tab and tick Show Disabled, and Disconnected devices, "Stereo Mix" is what you need but is disabled at the Sound driver level by many PC makers for [various reasons](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/whatever-happened-to-wave-out-mix).

.

[image]

Comment: It seems that link I posted is not loading right now, problems at Microsoft I suppose, please try it later or use this google cache page...http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Nj2ku8LNB7cJ:blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2008/07/11/whatever-happened-to-wave-out-mix.aspx&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1

Comment: i can't see stereo mix even though i check these two options shown in the picture

Comment: Try updating the sound driver, that is where that option is either enabled or disabled.